# Post-hoc test for GAMMs

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, post-hoc

I am analyzing my data with a generalized additive mixed model (GAMM) with the following structure:

```
y ~ Var1 + s(Var2) + s(Var3, bs="re")
```

Var1 is a factor with three levels and an unbalanced sample size (level1, n=7; level2, n=24; level3, n=5). I need a post-hoc test that checks pairwise comparisons between all levels, but all tests I found are for LMs, LMMs, or GLMMs. So, my questions are:

- Is there a post-hoc test I can use in this analysis?
- Since Var1 is parametric, can I use a post-hoc test for linear models instead (e.g., Tukey-Kramer test for unbalanced data)?

Comment: emmeans package in R supports post-hoc tests in GAMMs : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html#G